# What is the setting to change to allow the form to record more words?

Tags: php, html

I'm only able to insert a line of word and nothing more, how can I change it to record more words?

```html
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Description</label><br/><br/>
     <div class="col-md-11">
          <textarea type="text" class="form-control" rows="8" name="productinfo"><?php echo $product['productinfo']; ?></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could be a few things, what's your PHP code that handles recording the inputted text? How are you recording it? Database? What's your table structure? What's the field type & length?

Comment: i want to insert a paragraph of text, but im only able to insert one line of word into the database

Comment: what is the result, when you try below ? 
`<pre><?php echo $product['productinfo']; ?></pre>`
Are you able to see the whole text/paragraph ?

Comment: when i type "22222222222222222", i can see it. But when i type a paragraph of words, it disappear".

Comment: Show the table structure where you are saving `Description`..

Comment: What is the datatype and size of `productinfo`?